# I want to insert in database when I click a button in my View file using codeigniter 3.x

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I want to insert in database when I click button to store a single data only save value =1

```
<?phpif(intval($fspd->quantity) <= 0){echo '<form><input type="text" id="demo" value="" readonly ><a href="javascript:;"  onclick="clickdata()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Request For Restock</a></form>';}else{if($fspd->stock_status==1){?>
```

Comment: Find the controller that this form submits to, then inside that controller call your model that interacts with the database to add new values. If you don't want to use a standard MVC model, you can also just write a query inside your controller when it's hit. We can't write it for you though, try some code out and come back when you have a snippet we can work with.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe it will help you to seperate your code more into its pieces. LIKE PHP, HTML and Javascript But this is just an advice to write cleaner code
2. To answer your question: Have you looked into tutorials / documentation like this: https://www.studentstutorial.com/codeigniter/insert-data-codeIgniter

Comment: Can I use echo"<form action='<?php base_url()?>" method="POST"><input type="text" name="abc" value="1"><input type="submit" value="submit">'

Comment: This will only submit a html form to another page. Following your code it would be done in a POST-Request. The page you are sending to needs to handle the POST-Request and then needs to perform a mysql insert statement. 
These are the things you need to do. But i am sure, that there are hundreds of tutorials that show in detail what you need to do.